# Why doesn't json.loads() work for multiple columns?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to apply `json.loads` to multiple columns? If I do something like:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(json.loads)
```

I can apply it to each entry in `col1` and everything is fine. But if I do something like,

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3'] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3' ].apply(json.loads)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series.
```

Why doesn't this way work? Is it possible to apply it all at once or should I just do each column individually?

Comment: When you apply a function to multiple columns, each column becomes another argument to the function. But `json.loads()` only takes one JSON argument.

Comment: It doesn't apply the function separately to each column. It's calling `json.loads(col1, col2, col3)` for each row.

Comment: When you ask questions about dataframes, be sure to tag them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html, `apply` applies a function along an axis.

One way is to write a function that applies to the row series. The example doesn't apply the `json.loads` because the sample input would need to be json, but you can change the `apply_transform` function to meet your needs

(sorry for the `to_dict()` output but I have trouble getting dataframe output into text editors)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


columns = [
    "col1",
    "col2",
    "col3",
    "col4",
    "col5"
]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 5)), columns=columns)
df.to_dict()

# {'col1': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2},
#  'col2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 1},
#  'col3': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 3},
#  'col4': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 2},
#  'col5': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 0}}
```

You will notice that after the transformation, the columns have been doubled. You would replace the multiplication transformation with your own code

```py
def apply_transform(row):
    new_row = row.copy()
    for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']:
        new_row[col] = new_row[col] * 2  # apply your own transform here
    return new_row
    
df_new = df.apply(apply_transform, axis=1)
df_new.to_dict()

# {'col1': {0: 8, 1: 6, 2: 6, 3: 2, 4: 4},
#  'col2': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 2},
#  'col3': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 8, 4: 6},
#  'col4': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 2},
#  'col5': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 0}}
```

Comment: I think I'm missing the point here. I don't see how it's helpful. I'm just going to apply json.loads to the three columns individually like in my first line of code.

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers: the point is that you can apply a transformation function to a dataframe one row at a time (or one column at a time) by using `apply`. The function I show makes a copy of the row to not alter the source dataframe, transforms 3 columns by multiplying by 2, then returns the row to output. You can observe that the output for `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are all multiplied by 2. If you instead did `new_row[col] = json.loads(new_row[col])`, assuming the initial input is JSON, you'd get the result you were asking for